# Access information about pusher in Jenkins GitHub Branch Source plugin commit webhook payload

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm using the Jenkins GitHub Branch Source plugin together with a GitHub App in an Organization. The integration is working fine and jobs get created and triggered on commit as intended. The webhook is configured through the GitHub App

However, I would like to know who triggered the build. I can see the pushing GitHub account name in the webhook payload sent by GitHub, but I don't know how, or if I can access this information from my pipeline. Is this information available, and if so, how would I go about accessing it?

I'm not seeing any related information in the environment by default

Answer (score 1):

You can use GitHub API (need to get token from GitHub with proper permissions) to question the different information about the branch. One piece that may help you is that branch's last commit's author:

```
    withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: "github-app",
            passwordVariable: 'TOKEN', 
            usernameVariable: 'APP_ID')]) {

        def orgName = "YOUR_ORG_NAME"
        def projectName = "YOUR_PROJECT_NAME"
        def branch_name = env.CHANGE_ID ? env.CHANGE_BRANCH : env.BRANCH_NAME

        def url = "https://api.github.com/repos/${orgName}/${projectName}/branches/${branchName}"
        def headers = ' -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
                        -H "Authorization: token $TOKEN" '
        def the_email = sh (label: "Get Author email",
                returnStdout: true,
                script: "curl -s ${url} ${headers} | \
                      jq -r .commit.commit.author.email").trim().toLowerCase()
        println "the_email is ${the_email}"
    }
```

The "author" object looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "GitHubUser",
  "email": "77369350+githubuser@users.noreply.github.com",
  "date": "2022-06-28T10:20:12Z"
}
```

Naturally, there is more than one way to trigger a build. For example, it can also be triggered manually. In that case, the above won't work, and you need to search inside the "causes" of the build.

Comment: Unfortunately the last commit is not the same as the pusher in many cases. The commit.commit.author and commit.commit.commiter data is alos derived from git and not GitHub, and is just a reflection of what is in your git config, making the data too unreliable and spoofable for me to later use for further tasks. The causes is a clue though. While the current branch source plugin does not provide anything here, the older GitHub plugin does. There may be a way forward for me in porting that functionality to the branch source plugin.

Comment: FWIW, `.commit.committer.login` is the GitHub username.

Comment: Thanks, but commit.committer.login and commit.author.login also point to data derived from the git metadata and not the authentication context of the push. To anyone else reading this, I can't suggest relying on this metadata for anything that requires an audit trail. Fortunately the cause path has proven fruitful for us.